# Issue with for loops and recalling functions

Tags: javascript, methods, properties

I am making a simple battleships game where I press a button, and three boats are placed randomly. The first function placeBoat() calls the selectPos() function (which chooses a coordinate), then the placeBoat() function verifies if there is a boat there, using the property boatHitBox. If it passes the test, then buildBoat() and hitBox() are run, which places boat tiles and boat hitboxes respectively. The problem I have is that often, the boats are either one tile too short, or they are not placed at all. I think it is a problem with the hitBox() function, although I'm not sure... can anyone help?

```
    var xPos;
var xBoxPos;
var yPos;
var boatBoxPos;
var count;
var boatPos;
var hasBoat;
var boatHitBox;
var boatGrid = {

    placeBoat : function() {
        for (boatNum = 1; boatNum < 4; boatNum++) {
            console.log("boat placed now");
            this.selectPos();
            if (document.getElementById(boatPos).boatHitBox == 1) {
                console.log("FAILED!!!!!!");
                boatNum = 1;
                this.clearTable();
            }
            else {
                this.buildBoat();
            }
        }
    },

    selectPos : function() { 
        xPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8 + 1);
        yPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
    },
    hitBox : function() {
        for (count = 1; count < 5; count++) {
            boatBoxPos = "cell_" + xBoxPos + "_" + yPos;
            xBoxPos = xBoxPos + 1;
            document.getElementById(boatBoxPos).boatHitBox = 1;
            document.getElementById(boatBoxPos).innerHTML = "X";
        }
    },
    buildBoat : function() {
        for (boatLen = 1; boatLen < 4; boatLen++) {
            xBoxPos = xPos - 2;
            this.hitBox();
            boatPos = "cell_" + xPos + "_" + yPos;
            xPos = xPos + 1;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).hasBoat = 1;
            document.getElementById(boatPos).style.backgroundColor = "brown";
            console.log("placed one tile");
        }

    },
```

Comment: `placeBoat` only checks whether one position is filled, not all the positions of the boat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xBoxPos = xPos - 2;
```

subtracts 2 from xPos which starts out as a random number in the range 1 to 8. So randomly `xBoxPos` can take on values such as -1 and 0 when calculated. This generates cell id values (in `boatPos`) like "cell_-1_7". If you don't have negative x coordinate cells on the board, this crashes

```
 document.getElementById(boatPos).hasBoat
```

in the `boardGrid.buildBoat` function, leaving the board partially built. This is not to say other code problems will not reveal themselves but this one appears to need attention.

Comment: dude, I think that was the bug... I've been working on this for so long, thank you :DDD

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to know exactly what is happening without knowing the dimensions of your grid (accompanying html).  However...

There are three loops in your code sample.  Two of them go up to three (<4) and the hitBox goes up to four (<5).

Change the hitBox count to the same value as the boatLen.

Comment: I need hitbox to go behind the boat to avoid collisions